# window.postmessage() data is not recieved instantly rather than i have put a setTimeout function to pass the data

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using window.postmessage() to send the data across domains to a popup but, postmessage is not sending the data instantly i.e. when captured on other domain in constructor of a component the data is not coming. If given a setTimeout i.e. delay of around 1 sec then data is coming. What could be the issue?

Here's the code:

Parent:

```
var popup = window.open(
                "http://localhost:4300",
                'winname',
          );
    popup.postMessage('response', '*');
```

Popup-Window:

```
window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
console.log(event.data)}
```

I should be getting data as response but I am getting data as undefined in console.

Also,
If i put the code below in Parent:

```
setTimeout(() => {
              popup.postMessage('response', "http://localhost:4300");
            }, 2000);
```

I am able to get the data as "response" in console in popup.

I want to get rid of setTimeout and get the data as soon as poosible.
Please help.

Comment: Please Share some code

Comment: What do you mean by "*when captured on other domain in constructor of a component*"?

Comment: What is happening during that second?

Comment: is the page loaded before you call postMessage?

Comment: Added the code required for the issue. Please check

Comment: Can't make much sense of this, with the info given so far. The document in the popup will not be done loading and initializing whatever code you have running in there, _immediately_ - so if you got no reaction at all, that would be understandable. But if you get undefined logged to console, that would mean the message event handler inside your popup was already registered ...? But then it would not make sense to me, that it did not receive any data.